# C# Visual Studio でファイル配布を目的としたインストーラを作成したい。

Tags: c#, visual-studio

掲題の件、プロジェクトの出力ファイル(exe等）ではなく、例えばClickOnceの発行物など任意のファイルをサーバ上の特定のディレクトリに配置するインストーラを作成したいと思っています。

上記の要件の場合、普通のセットアッププロジェクトを作成して、
ファイルを追加していくのが一般的でしょうか？
セットアッププロジェクトにも、いくつか種類があるようで（Cab ProjectやSetup Wizardなど）
どれが適切なのか分かり難かったため、アドバイス等ありましたら
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己レスです。通常のセットアッププロジェクトにClickOnce発行物を追加していく形でインストーラを
作成できました。